# QUALIFY-Like Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table has 2 columns: `Emp_Name` and `Emp_NR`.

It can happen that one `Emp_Name` value has 2 different `Emp_NR` values.

I would like to create a `SELECT` statement that gets only a single value of `Emp_Name` and `Emp_NR`

The statement should be something like in Teradata:

```
SELECT 
    Emp_Name,
    Emp_NR
FROM Table
QUALIFY Row_Number OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_Name ORDER BY Emp__NR DESC) = 1
```

In addition to that, I would like to get the highest `Emp_NR` that is assigned to a specific `Emp_Name`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    Emp_Name,
    Emp_NR,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_Name ORDER BY Emp__NR DESC) as Nub FROM Table) AS Temp WHERE Nub = 1

Comment: @Blim But `select *` introduces a new column named _Nub_ in the result set

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did everything right.

```
SELECT Emp_NR, Emp_Name
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_Name ORDER BY Emp_NR DESC) AS RN, Emp_Name, Emp_NR
    FROM YourTable
    ) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```

This is correct syntax.

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to use `ORDER BY` combined with `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Emp_Name, Emp_NR
FROM Table
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_Name ORDER BY Emp_NR DESC);
```

Performance may be slight worse than the solution using subquery.

Comment: This is really the exact answer to the question which was asked, which was looking for an equivalent to `QUALIFY` in SQL Server.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER = 1` will only ever give you a single row, your `WITH TIES` is the same as `RANK() = 1` and not ROW_NUMBER at all.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim `ROW_NUMBER = 1 will only ever give you a single row, your WITH TIES is the same as RANK() = 1 and not ROW_NUMBER at all.` The whole clue to get first row per partition is usage of  the `WITH TIES` clause. The solution must work accross all partitions. Here concrete example: https://dbfiddle.uk/uBadBmSP

Comment: Oh, I see the indirectness, this is rather clever!