# how to filter data using qualify row_number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am trying to use QUALIFY to filter the data without seccess (in SQL SERVER)
also, I do not want to create a table with the row_number in the SELECT statement and then use WHERE clause.

```
select *
from [dbo].[DWH_TicketThread_View]
where 1=1
and threadtype in (313,347,349,385,392,417)
and TicketId = 651353
qualify row_number() over(partition by ticketid order by updatedate desc) = 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QUALIFY-Like Function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917686/qualify-like-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: This question is completely clear to me, and I don't understand why it has been closed with the given reason above.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. the answer is well written and understood even to a basic-understanding audience. Tim thank you for solving my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not support `QUALIFY` which appears in other databases such as Teradata.  Here is one way to write your query in a similar way, without a formal subquery, using a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM [dbo].[DWH_TicketThread_View]
WHERE threadtype IN (313, 347, 349, 385, 392, 417) AND TicketId = 651353
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY updatedate DESC);
```

But the above is actually not that performant, so more typically we would in fact use a subquery here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY updatedate DESC) rn
    FROM [dbo].[DWH_TicketThread_View]
    WHERE threadtype IN (313, 347, 349, 385, 392, 417) AND TicketId = 651353
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```